# How to disable new mouse find feature in windows 10/11?

Tags: windows-10, mouse

When double press ctrl-left there is a new feature in Windows that darkens your screen and shows a white circle where your pointer is.

I have the "find you mouse option" disabled in the mouse menu. But it only deactivates the old circles.

Is there a way to disable this? [image: super annoying]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are seeing the PowerToys Find My Mouse feature.

To disable, go to *PowerToys Settings > Mouse Utilities*
and disable the option "Enable Find My Mouse":

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The feature is part of the windows powertoys,
you can disable it in the options

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).